# $f'(x_0)$ exists, then it is continuous in $x_0$, but why can $f(x)$ be discontinuous in the neighborhood of $x_0$?

Tags: calculus

$f'(x_0)$ exists, then it is continuous in $x_0$, but why can $f(x)$ be discontinuous in the neighborhood of $x_0$?

**If $f'(x_0)$ exists,  wouldn't the left and right derivatives of $f(x)$ exist at $x_0$?**

**If the left and right derivatives of $f(x)$ exist at $x_0$, doesn't that mean that $f(x)$ is continuous in the neighborhood of $x_0$?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because continuity and differentiability are highly localized properties.

Consider a simple example: $f(x)=x^2$ for rationals and $f(x)=0$ otherwise.

Then $f'(0)$ exists and is equal to zero. But $f$ is not continuous on any interval around zero.

Comment: $f'(0)=0$, so $f(x) is continuous at 0, but  $f(0) is continuous with whom? Not both sides of zero?@symplectomorphic

Comment: The question "continuous with whom" makes no sense, so I'm not sure how to help you. Perhaps you think it's impossible for a function to be continuous at only a single point. In that case, you're again mistaken. Consider $f(x)=x$ for $x$ rational and $f(x)=0$ otherwise. This function is continuous only at the origin; it is discontinuous everywhere else.

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't express myself clearly."Perhaps you think it's impossible for a function to be continuous at only a single point."That's exactly what I want to ask. Now I think I got it. Thank you!

Comment: @ClancyZeng The more surprising fact is that most of the continuous functions are nowhere differentiable. This is a consequence of Baire's cathegory theorem.